# Event listener for window.stripe

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe integration in a React web front-end. My payment component attempts to run…

```
componentDidLoad() {
  if ( window.hasOwnProperty('Stripe') ) {
    this.setState({stripe: window.stripe(config.stripeKey)})
  }
}
```

This sporadically fails as sometimes the React app will boot and get the component loaded before window.stripe exists. I’m currently resolving this with…

```
componentDidLoad() {
  this.watchStripe = setInterval( () => {
    if (!props.stripe && isBrowser && window.Stripe) {
      this.setState({stripe: window.stripe(config.stripeKey)})
      clearInterval(this.watchStripe)
    }
  }, 100)
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this, something that doesn't require an interval timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [Advanced integrations section](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/#advanced-integrations) they suggest doing

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (window.Stripe) {
      this.setState({stripe: window.Stripe('pk_test_12345')});
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#stripe-js').addEventListener('load', () => {
        // Create Stripe instance once Stripe.js loads
        this.setState({stripe: window.Stripe('pk_test_12345')});
      });
    }
  }
```

This adds an event listener for the `load` event on the `script` element that loads Stripe and sets the state when it is available (*so no continuous polling with `setInterval`,`setTimeout` is needed*)